# Evaluting limits using epsilon delta definition

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}     \dfrac{(1+y^2)\sin x}{x}=1$$
Verify using epsilon delta defination. 
I am unable to reduce this to the neighbourhood form. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$. We'll show that there exist $\delta>0$ that if $|(x,y)-(0,0)| < \delta$ then $|\frac{\sin x (1+y^2)}{x}-1|<\epsilon$

We know that

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$

and

$\lim_{y \to 0}1+y^2=1$

so there exist $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$:

$0<|x-0|<\delta_1$ implies $|\frac{\sin x}{x}-1|<\min{\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{3}},\frac{\epsilon}{3}}$

$|y-0|<\delta_2$ implies $|1+y^2-1|<\min{\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{3}},\frac{\epsilon}{3}}$

Let $\delta=\min{\delta_1,\delta_2}$. Next if $ |(x,y)-(0,0)|<\delta$ then $|x-0|<\delta$ and $|y-0|<\delta$, so:

$|\frac{\sin x (1+y^2)}{x}-1|=|(\frac{\sin x}{x}-1)(1+y^2-1)+\frac{\sin x}{x}-1+(1+y^2)-1| \leq |(\frac{\sin x}{x}-1)(1+y^2-1)|+|\frac{\sin x}{x}-1|+|(1+y^2)-1|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}=\epsilon$

Comment: Minor technical point: you need $0 < |x-0| < \delta_1$, not just $|x-0| < \delta_1$, because $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is undefined when $x = 0$.  But it is easy enough to insert "$0 < $" in the few places where you need it.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{(1+y^2)sinx}{x} - 1 = \dfrac{sinx}{x} - 1 + y^2\cdot \dfrac{sinx}{x}$.

It is well-known that $\dfrac{sinx}{x} \to 1$ as $x \to 0$. This means for $\epsilon = 1$, there is $\delta_1 > 0$ such that: if $0 < |x| < \delta_1 \to \left|\dfrac{sinx}{x} - 1\right| < 1$. So: $\left|\dfrac{sinx}{x}\right| - |1| \leq \left|\dfrac{sinx}{x} - 1\right| < 1 \to \left|\dfrac{sinx}{x}\right| < 1 + 1 = 2$.

Also $y^2 \to 0$ as $y \to 0$. This means for a given $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta_2 > 0$ such that if $0 < |y| < \delta_2$, then $|y^2| = |y^2 - 0| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{4}$, and also there is a $\delta_3 > 0$ such that if $0 < |x| < \delta_3$, then $\left|\dfrac{sinx}{x} - 1\right| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$. So if we choose $\delta = min\{\delta_1, \delta_2, \delta_3\} > 0$, then if $0 < |(x,y)| < \delta$, then $|x| < \delta$, and $|y| < \delta$ and then:

$\left|\dfrac{(1+y^2)sinx}{x} - 1\right| \leq \left|\dfrac{sinx}{x} - 1\right| + y^2\cdot \left|\dfrac{sinx}{x}\right| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} + \dfrac{\epsilon}{4}\cdot 2 = \epsilon$.